# Custom .NET Remoting IServerChannelSink

Tags: c#, .net, remoting, .net-remoting

i have a client-server application which uses .NET Remoting communication. For authentication reasons i had to write a custom [IClientChannelSink](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8xkh1tek%28v=VS.80%29.aspx) to insert a session cookie into the HTTP-requests.
On the server side i also wrote a custom [IServerChannelSink](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t2695x5d%28v=VS.80%29.aspx) to read some information the server needs from the HTTP-request headers.

The client side works fine, but on the server side i always get the following error:

> System.ArgumentNullException was unhandled by user code   Message=No
>   message was deserialized prior to calling the DispatchChannelSink.
>   Parameter name: requestMsg   Source=mscorlib   ParamName=requestMsg
>   StackTrace:
>          at
>   System.Runtime.Remoting.Channels.DispatchChannelSink.ProcessMessage(IServerChannelSinkStack
>   sinkStack, IMessage requestMsg, ITransportHeaders requestHeaders,
>   Stream requestStream, IMessage& responseMsg, ITransportHeaders&
>   responseHeaders, Stream& responseStream)
>          at
>   MyAuthentication.MyServerChannelSink.ProcessMessage(IServerChannelSinkStack
>   sinkStack, IMessage requestMsg, ITransportHeaders requestHeaders,
>   Stream requestStream, IMessage& responseMsg, ITransportHeaders&
>   responseHeaders, Stream& responseStream) in
>   C:\Dev\MyAuthentication\MyServerChannelSink.cs:line 82
>          at
>   System.Runtime.Remoting.Channels.BinaryServerFormatterSink.ProcessMessage(IServerChannelSinkStack
>   sinkStack, IMessage requestMsg, ITransportHeaders requestHeaders,
>   Stream requestStream, IMessage& responseMsg, ITransportHeaders&
>   responseHeaders, Stream& responseStream)
>          at
>   System.Runtime.Remoting.Channels.Http.HttpServerTransportSink.ServiceRequest(Object
>   state)
>          at
>   System.Runtime.Remoting.Channels.SocketHandler.ProcessRequestNow()
>   InnerException:

My "ProcessMessage"-methodlooks as follows:

```
public ServerProcessing ProcessMessage(IServerChannelSinkStack sinkStack, IMessage requestMsg, ITransportHeaders requestHeaders, Stream requestStream, out IMessage responseMsg, out ITransportHeaders responseHeaders, out Stream responseStream)
{
    // Pre-processing before sending the message to the next sink in the chain
    object state = null;
    ProcessRequest(requestMsg, requestHeaders, ref requestStream, ref state);

    /* Call the next sink in the chain */
    sinkStack.Push(this, state);
    ServerProcessing serverProcessing = this.NextChannelSink.ProcessMessage(sinkStack, requestMsg, requestHeaders, requestStream, out responseMsg, out responseHeaders, out responseStream);

    // Processing from sink further in the chain has completed. Now do any post-processing before returning to the previous sink in the chain.
    ProcessResponse(null, responseHeaders, ref responseStream, state);

    return serverProcessing;
}
```

Would be great if anyone can tell me whats wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've solved my problem. Since i don't use the channel sinks to do any serialization i also don't want to handle the message deserialization by myself. The  following implemention works fine:

```
public ServerProcessing ProcessMessage(IServerChannelSinkStack sinkStack, IMessage requestMsg, ITransportHeaders requestHeaders, Stream requestStream, out IMessage responseMsg, out ITransportHeaders responseHeaders, out Stream responseStream)
{
    // Pre-processing before sending the message to the next sink in the chain
    object state = null;
    ProcessRequest(requestMsg, requestHeaders, ref requestStream, ref state);

    ServerProcessing serverProcessing;
    if (requestMsg != null)
    {
        /* Call the next sink in the chain */
        sinkStack.Push(this, state);
        serverProcessing = this.NextChannelSink.ProcessMessage(sinkStack, requestMsg, requestHeaders, requestStream, out responseMsg, out responseHeaders, out responseStream);
        sinkStack.Pop(this);
    }
    else
    {
        responseMsg = null;
        responseHeaders = null;
        responseStream = null;
        serverProcessing = ServerProcessing.Complete;
    }

    // Processing from sink further in the chain has completed. Now do any post-processing before returning to the previous sink in the chain.
    ProcessResponse(null, responseHeaders, ref responseStream, state);

    return serverProcessing;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Under certain circumstances the requestMsg parameter could be
null. So you have to handle those cases. For example another server channel sink
is calling your ProcessMessage function with requestMsg set to null!

EDIT: Provided link to a sample.
Here is link to sample of a server sink:[Server Sink](http://simpledotnet.googlecode.com/svn-history/r616/trunk/src/Simple.Services/Services/Remoting/Serialization/CustomBinaryServerFormatterSink.cs)

Comment: Do you have any sample code how to handle these case? I couldn't find any reference implementation for a IClientChannelSink in the web. My IClientChannelSink implementation should only read some values from the HTTP-header but not alter the request message in any way.

Comment: There is a sample implementation in the MSDN. But it seems to be similar to my implementation http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.remoting.channels.iserverchannelsink(v=VS.80).aspx

Answer (score 0):

By creating your server channel

```
TcpServerChannel oTcpChannel =
    new TcpServerChannel(oTcpChannelConfiguration, oServerSinkProvider, oAuthority);
```

You can set `oServerSinkProvider = null` and the system will support a default sink provider. You can als specify your own formatter, for example a soap formatter for a TCP channel or a binary formatter for an http channel: `SoapServerFormatterSinkProvider` or `BinaryServerFormatterSinkProvider`.

However if you support your own server sink, you must implement your own formatter too. You can do so in your set section of your function `IServerChannelSinkProvider.Next` by:

```
  set
  {
    if ( value != null )
    {
      nextProvider = new BinaryServerFormatterSinkProvider ();
      nextProvider.Next = value;
    }
    else
    {
      nextProvider = value;
    };
  }
```

Then the next provider does the job of fomatting, binary formatting in this case.